# "Перед тем(,) как..." — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая или нет: "Перед тем как ставить телевизор, нужно решить, где будет стоять стол". Или же: "Перед тем как ставить телевизор нужно решить, где будет стоять стол"?
И почему?

Comment: juki, опять Вы со своей самодеятельностью лезете! Лучше на вопросы отвечайте хоть иногда.

Answer (score 2):

"Нужно решить" - главное предложение. Решить что? - где будет стоять стол. Решить когда? - перед тем как ставить телевизор

Answer (score 0):

Перед "нужно" запятая ставится обязательно, т.к. разделяет придаточную часть и главную. верный вариант написания - первый. Второй  с ошибкой.
  Есть еще одно место, где возможна запятая: "Перед тем, как..." или "перед_ тем как". Допустимы оба варианта. Я выделила бы "перед тем" голосом и паузой и поставила бы запятую.